# Elegantly output several dataframes in the same Excel sheet with R

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I am currently trying to output several R data frames in the same Excel Sheet. 
I have a script that generates 270 tables. Basically, I would like to group the tables this way:

- 15 tables per sheet
- 6 sheets per file
- 3 files.

I have thought about grouping them the following way:

- 1 table per sheet
- 15 sheets per file
- 6 files per directory
- 3 directories

But it means that I would have to jump between each file whilst working, which is not really practical. I also thought about grouping the 15 tables sets in one data frame using `cbinds` and `rbinds` and empty rows/columns to mark the separation between them. However, I am not happy with this solution as it is not really elegant.

I don't know if any package offers the possibility to do this or if xslx/Rexcel packages do, but I haven't found it. When I try to find an answer to this question, I only find topics about writing in different Excel sheets.

If anyone has the solution if would be pleased to know about it :).

Comment: In `XLConnect::writeWorksheet`, all arguments are vectorized, so it accepts a list of data frames, as well as vectors for the `startRow` argument. With some clever arithmetic you can write a list of data frames to a single sheet with gaps between each one.

Comment: Great package and great method thanks! It was actually the kind of function I was looking for! I still need to figure out some little details but it gives me the output I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently moved away form **XLConnect**, but in the past I have used a function similar to the one below for this sort of thing.

```
require(XLConnect)
write_excel_gap <- function(path = NULL,
                            data_list = NULL,
                            gap = 1,
                            sheet = "Sheet1",
                            header = TRUE,
                            firstRow = 1,
                            add = FALSE,
                            addSheet = TRUE,
                            style = TRUE,...){

    stopifnot(length(gap) > 0,!is.null(path),!is.null(data_list))

    if (add){
        wb <- loadWorkbook(path,create = FALSE)
    }else{
        wb <- loadWorkbook(path,create = TRUE)
    }

    if (addSheet){
        createSheet(wb,sheet)
    }
    if (!style){
        setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")
    }

    n <- length(data_list)
    ng <- length(gap)
    dl_rows <- sapply(data_list,nrow)

    if (ng == 1){
        sr <- c(firstRow,firstRow + head(cumsum(dl_rows),-1)) + 
            c(0,cumsum(rep(gap,n-1)))
    }else{
        if(ng != n-1){
            warning("Length of gap is not one less than length of data_list. 
                            \nGap will be recycled as needed.")
        }
        sr <- c(firstRow,firstRow + head(cumsum(dl_rows),-1)) + 
            c(0,cumsum(gap))
    }

    if (header){
        writeWorksheet(object=wb,
                       data=data_list[[1]],
                       sheet=sheet,
                       startRow=firstRow,
                       header = TRUE,...)
        sr <- sr[-1] + 1
        writeWorksheet(object = wb,
                       data = data_list[-1],
                       sheet = sheet,
                       startRow = sr,
                       header = FALSE,...)
    }else{
        writeWorksheet(object = wb,
                       data = data_list,
                       sheet = sheet,
                       startRow = sr,
                       header = FALSE,...)
    }
    saveWorkbook(wb)
 }
```

Comment: Might I ask what you have moved to instead of XLConnect?  I have been using that a long time, even though the Java dependencies cause problems on Java updates.

Comment: @lawyeR I switched to **openxlsx**. It doesn't have quite as much functionality as XLConnect, in terms of vectorized arguments or fancy formatting, but it's enough for what I need. And no Java. **readxl** is sort of the hot new thing these days, but it only reads data, it doesn't write data, which is a non-starter for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I do a lot of formatting the output, with colors and bold and zebra striping, so I will stay with XLConnect.  I did not realize readxl doesn't write data.  That is a half-solution at best!  Regards